# Decent SMTP client in C++

Tags: c++, smtpclient, ssl, smtplib

I'd like to have a decent SMTP client-side library in C++ with permissive license (LGPL, BSD, MIT-X, ...). It must have at least rfc821 and rfc2487 conformity and preferably rfc3207 conformity.

I have found some that have not met all the requirements:

1. Poco SMTP
2. DataReel SMTP
3. vmime

If you have any, please kindly share. Thank you!

Comment: vmime !!! compilation with mingw & msys: http://omgwtfbbq.nl/it-stuff/howto-compiling-libvmime-on-mingwmsys/

Answer (score 2):

Linux, Windows or both?  I know of a great free Windows client, which is part of [Ultimate TCP/IP](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/UltimateTCPIP.aspx).

Comment: I want cross-platform one. Thanks anyway!